# Why does my ImageBackground not extent to the bottom of the screen anymore?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have wrapped my ImageBackground in a ScrollView but now my content does not extend to the bottom anymore.  FYI the ScrollView goes all the way to the bottom but the Imagebackground does not. Without the ScrollView the content goes all the way to the bottom without any space beneath it. Does anyone know why my ScrollView is preventing my ImageBackground from reaching the bottom of the screen? I have left out the styles that are not relevant to the outer content.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {View, StyleSheet, Text, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity, Image, ActivityIndicator, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import Header from '../../components/Header/Header';
import Loader from "../../components/Login/Loader";
import {loadCustomerOrderDetails} from '../../actions/AppActions'
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import {createIconSetFromIcoMoon} from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import selection from '../../selection';

const MBIcon = createIconSetFromIcoMoon(selection);

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props.dispatch(loadCustomerOrderDetails(this.props.customerId));
    }

    render() {
        const {isLoading, details} = this.props.customerData;
        const {invoices, unsubmittedOrders, itemIssues, deliveryStats} = details;
        let customerName = 'Select Account...';
        if (unsubmittedOrders && unsubmittedOrders.customerName) {
            customerName = unsubmittedOrders.customerName;
        }
        return (
            <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                <Header style={styles.header}/>
                <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/loginBG.jpg')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>

                        <View>
                            <Image style={styles.mblogo} source={require('../../assets/mb_logo.png')} />
                        </View>

                        {isLoading &&
                            <ActivityIndicator
                                style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}
                                animating={true}
                                size='large'
                            />
                        }

                    </ImageBackground>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

Home.propTypes = {
    customerData: PropTypes.object,
    customerId: PropTypes.string,
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const {customerData, app} =  state;
    return {
        customerData: customerData,
        customerId: app.customerId
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        position: 'relative'
    },
    header: {
        height: 200,
        width: '100%',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0
    },
    backgroundImage: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.45)',
        width: null,
        height: '100%',
        marginTop: 55, 
        flex: 1, 
        position: 'relative', 
        bottom: 0
    },
    content: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    homeSection: {
        flex: 2,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: '90%',
        margin: 'auto',
    },
    cartBtnContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginVertical: 8
    },
    footerBtn: {
        width: '45%',
        height: 48,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 24,
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: can you share the project by any means?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to put `ScrollView` inside `ImageBackground` like `<ImageBackground><ScrollView>....</ScrollView></ImageBackground>`?

Comment: You should to add a resizeMode prop with either 'stretch/contain/cover' as value for your background image component.

Comment: Use Dimensions package from react native

Comment: @gaback your answer solved it if you want to make it official I'll give you the credit

Comment: @Tanya made it the answer below. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `ScrollView` inside `ImageBackground`:

```
<ImageBackground>
    <ScrollView>
    ......
    </ScrollView>
</ImageBackground>
```